# Non-repeating random variable in SASS

Tags: css, random, sass, repeat

I'm working on something where I have a list of 5 colors and I need to use these 5 color in 10 different `div` elements. But each color needs to be used twice and in a random order. Using the `random()` function doesn't really work because I need the numbers not to repeat.

What I have for now is this:

```
$colorList: #32ba81,#65e028,#4791e0,#f44130,#ff7811;

@mixin getColor($colorCont) {
    background-color: nth($colorList, $colorCont);
}

$j: 0;

@for $i from 1 to 6 {
    @if ($i < 6) {
        $j: $j + 1;
    }       
    .card:nth-of-type(#{random(10)}) {
        @include getColor($j);
    }
    .card:nth-of-type(#{random(10)}) {
        @include getColor($j);
    }
}
```

How can I generate 10 random numbers for `nth-of-type` without them repeating?

Note: I have 2 `.card:nth-of-type` to use one color in two `div` elements at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are standard methods to generate non-repeating random numbers.  For a small set, you shuffle an array:

1. Put the numbers [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4] into an array.
2. Shuffle the array.  Use the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle if you don't have a built-in array shuffle.
3. Pick off the numbers from the shuffled array, using them to index the colours.

Comment: I understand the idea, I just don't know if SASS has enough tools to let me implement that exact way.

Comment: Try implementing the array as a list.  For the F-Y shuffle you need to be able to swap two elements of the list.  That might need an extra variable, or you might need a whole second list to do the swapping.

Comment: I'll try to work something out. Thanks for the help, that'll be the only possible thing to do by now.

Comment: I found a way to do that. It's in here https://codepen.io/Guips/pen/gvmbJY